# Ubuntu 18.04 - No wifi adapter found problem

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, bluetooth

Just installed an Ubuntu next to the Windows 10 as a second system.
At first installed an Ubuntu 19.10 but the problem occured so i thought that maybe if i turn it into Ubuntu 18.04 it will be solved but unfortunately not.
I can do nothing, i cant connect to the wifi, i cant connect by USB tethering or by Bluetooth tethering using my phone so I cant install drivers.
i tried to install them using a pendrive but dont have an internet so i cant use `make` command.

I have an asus vivobook 15
How can i solve this problem? I think ive searched the whole internet already

lspci

```
04:00 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

lshw -C Network

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED
description: Network controller
       product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b4200000-b420ffff
*-network
description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: enp0s20f0u6
       serial: 92:d1:af:f9:cb:15
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device link=yes multicast=yes
```

lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
Subsystem: AzureWave RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter 
[1a3b:3040]
0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

The answear given in a flagged post doesnt work for my problem

After 'nano Makefile' the line n 152 is 'CONFIG_PLATFORM_ARM_WMT = n'

Comment: This one doesnt work. After 'nano Makefile' the line n 152 is 'CONFIG_PLATFORM_ARM_WMT = n'

Comment: Please try @vchrizz answer further down.

Comment: sudo apt-get install doesnt work either

Comment: Do you have a working internet connection? Did you preceed the command with: `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: I dont have a working internet connection

Comment: Wifi doesnt work and hotspot from my phone too and i dont have a cable

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you install it in about five minutes.

Donkeyday: "Hey, friend, can I borrow your ethernet connection for just a few minutes? I brought along six of your favorite beverage."

Friend: "Sure, Donk, glad to help you! Let me put a couple of those beverages on ice."

You then open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall git dkms build-essential linux-headers-generic
git clone https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce
cd rtl8821ce
chmod +x dkms-install.sh
chmod +x dkms-remove.sh
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

Your wireless should now be working. Detach the ethernet, thank the friend and enjoy!

Here is how to do it in about five days...maybe.

Go here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/

Select Bionic in the drop-down box. Search for git, dkms, linux-headers-generic and build-essential. Be sure to locate their dependencies and the dependencies of the dependencies. Be sure to download the correct version, either 32- or 64-bit. Once you've download about fifteen or so packages on another computer, transfer them with a USB stick or similar to the desktop of your Ubuntu computer. Open a terminal and install them:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

It may complain that a package is missing a dependency. If so, download that and add it to the desktop and try again.

Write many posts on the forum to tell old Chili how you're stuck. Rinse and repeat.

Once that's all done, get this file: https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce/archive/master.zip

```
unzip master.zip
cd rtl8821ce
chmod +x dkms-install.sh
chmod +x dkms-remove.sh
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

Reboot and your wireless should now be working.

Comment: it says media change: please insert the disc labeled after sudo apt-get install --reinstall git dkms build-essential linux-headers-generic

Comment: @RanFang Please start your own new question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you find this problem when you entered Ubuntu after shutting down from Windows (not restarting)? I found that the problem could be solved by entering Windows again and rebooting to enter Ubuntu.